# R data.table binary OR across specific columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with ~300 columns and 50000000 rows that looks something like this:

```
DT = data.table(spr_1.x=c(1,0,0,1),
spr_15.x=c(0,1,0,1),spr_99.x=c(0,0,0,1),spr_1.y=c(0,0,0,1),
spr_15.y=c(1,1,0,1),spr_99.y=c(1,1,0,1),spr_1.z=c(1,0,0,1),
spr_15.z=c(0,1,0,1),spr_99.z=c(0,0,0,1))
```

What I need is binary OR between spr_1, spr_15, and spr_99 columns as:

```
   spr_1.x spr_15.x spr_99.x spr_1.y spr_15.y spr_99.y spr_1.z spr_15.z spr_99.z spr_1 spr_15 spr_99
1:       1        0        0       0        1        1       1        0        0     1      1      1
2:       0        1        0       0        1        1       0        1        0     0      1      1
3:       0        0        0       0        0        0       0        0        0     0      0      0
4:       1        1        1       1        1        1       1        1        1     1      1      1
```

I can do it using the following code:

```
for (i in c('spr_1','spr_15','spr_99')){
x=paste0(i,'.x')
y=paste0(i,'.y')
z=paste0(i,'.z')
DT[,(i):=Reduce(`|`, .SD),.SDcols=c(x,y,z)]}
for (j in c('spr_1','spr_15','spr_99')) DT[, (j):= as.numeric(get(j))]
```

but, is there a better, faster, and less RAM-intensive approach?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are willing to try (`data.table` version `1.14.3` for row-wise operation)

```
for (i in c('spr_1','spr_15','spr_99')) {
     DT[,(i) := max(.SD), .SDcols=patterns(paste0(i,"\\.")),by = .I]    
}
```

For stable `data.table` version,

```
for (i in c('spr_1','spr_15','spr_99')) {
     DT[,(i) := Reduce(pmax,.SD),.SDcols=patterns(paste0(i,"\\."))]    
}
```

P.S: It's better to use `do.call` to replace `Reduce` here. see @r2evans 's answer.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the advice. It returns all 1, but I modified your code as: "for (i in c('spr_1','spr_15','spr_99')) {
  DT[,(i):=as.integer(Reduce(`|`, .SD)), .SDcols=patterns(paste0(i,"\\."))]    
}" and the results are OK now. BTW, I get the same results with and without "by=.I". Is it necessary?

Comment: If you use `Reduce` for row-wise operation,  then `by = .I` is not necessary.  I use `max` to find the max of each row,  which is equiviliant to Reduce.

Comment: If you new the newest version, it will not returns all 1.

Comment: Strangely, in my case "by=.I" doesn't return correct result. However "by=1:nrow(DT)" does; such as: "for (i in c('spr_1','spr_15','spr_99')) {
  DT[,(i) := max(.SD), .SDcols=patterns(paste0(i,"\\.")),by = 1:nrow(DT)]    
}". Why would that be? I thought "by=.I" and "by=1:nrow(DT)" are equivalent.

Comment: I am running "> packageVersion("data.table")
[1] ‘1.14.0’"

Comment: You can use `data.table::update.dev.pkg()` to get the latest development version.

Comment: FYI, `Reduce` is not doing row-wise operations here, it is executing once per *loop*. You get the same results with `DT[,(i) := do.call(pmax, .SD), .SDcols=...]`, and with 40M rows (same columns as above, just repeated), `do.call(..)` is about 15-20% faster. (And row-wise operations here would be *very bad* for performance. Much better to stick with vectorized operations with `pmax`.)

Comment: With `by=.I`, isn't `max` being called once per row? If so, I can't imagine that being a competitive approach when we're talking millions of rows.

Comment: @r2evans Agree with your kind comment. It's not a competitive approach for large row size. Thanks a lot.

Comment: FYI, feel free to keep `do.call(pmax, .SD)` in your code if you'd like. The only reason I made the answer is since it was way too much as a comment, but there was a lot to get out. Do whichever you prefer, but you certainly have my permission (if that's even needed) to switch over to `do.call`. Over to you :-)

Answer (score 2):

Formalizing my comments above into a benchmark. This is not a new answer (other than recommending `do.call` over `Reduce`, but that's not very novel), just an extended comment. (I'll delete it if it is too far out of context.)

```r
DTbig <- rbindlist(replicate(1e7, DT, simplify=FALSE))
nrow(DTbig)
# [1] 40000000
```

Proof of the `do.call(pmax, .SD)` concept:

```r
DTbig2 <- copy(DTbig)
for (i in c('spr_1','spr_15','spr_99')) {
  DTbig2[,(i) := Reduce(pmax, .SD), .SDcols = patterns(paste0(i, "\\."))]
}
for (i in c('spr_1','spr_15','spr_99')) {
  DTbig[,(i) := do.call(pmax, .SD), .SDcols = patterns(paste0(i, "\\."))]
}
identical(DTbig, DTbig2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Benchmark:

```r
bench::mark(
orig = {
  for (i in c('spr_1','spr_15','spr_99')) {
    DTbig[,(i) := +Reduce(`|`, .SD), .SDcols = patterns(paste0(i, "\\."))]
  }
},
Reduce = {
  for (i in c('spr_1','spr_15','spr_99')) {
    DTbig[,(i) := Reduce(pmax,.SD), .SDcols=patterns(paste0(i,"\\."))]
  }
},
docall = {
  for (i in c('spr_1','spr_15','spr_99')) {
    DTbig[,(i) := do.call(pmax, .SD), .SDcols = patterns(paste0(i, "\\."))]
  }
}, iterations = 20)
# # A tibble: 3 x 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory               time       gc       
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>               <list>     <list>   
# 1 orig       956.22ms    1.08s     0.939    2.68GB     2.35     6    15      6.39s <NULL> <Rprofmem [109 x 3]> <bench_tm~ <tibble ~
# 2 Reduce        1.04s    1.07s     0.943    2.68GB     2.83     5    15       5.3s <NULL> <Rprofmem [306 x 3]> <bench_tm~ <tibble ~
# 3 docall     847.69ms 863.73ms     1.15     1.79GB     1.15    10    10      8.72s <NULL> <Rprofmem [97 x 3]>  <bench_tm~ <tibble ~
```

(I'm *really* not sure how `iterations=` is interpreted ...)

FYI, the `+` in `` +Reduce(`|`, .SD) `` is analogous to your follow-up `as.numeric` without the extra step.

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark test.